# How to write script for comparing Search results using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, ide

could someone help with the commands to compare two variables using Selenium IDE?

Let's say, I print '**jacket**' and in drop down I have : "**Jackets 3**", -> click enter -> search results page shows '**3 items found**' 
I need to compare these two variables and if they are equal - test passed.  Would be very happy to any help!